# Problems with access to run CHKDSK

Tags: chkdsk

I am trying to run `ChkDsk` on my Windows 10 laptop before upgrading to an iMac.  I am the main user and access has been denied because I do not have sufficient privileges.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the command prompt in administrator mode. To do it, right-click the windows start button at the left-down corner of the screen and then select *'command prompt (administrator)'* (It can also say *'Windows Powershell (administrator)'*)

Once you are at the command prompt, type `cd ..` twice, so you can be at the main directory (It **must** be at the root of the disk, e.g. C:\ or D:.

Now type the `chkdsk` command again.

---

### In case you can't see the administrator functionality, I recommend to:

1. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > type `netplwiz`.
2. A window will open with the available users > Select your current user > Go to Properties
3. Go to Group membership > Select the Administrator box *(if it's checked, select administrators at the 'others' box)*
4. Reset your computer and retry to run the command using the same steps as before.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I had done all that. It then asks me to reboot and sign in again, which I do. Then I try to run CHKDSK and I still only have access to C:\Users\Gina.

Comment: I've modified the answer. Try following these steps. I hope it will help!